# How to check if a commutative ring is Gorenstein.

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose I have a ring $R$ defined by generators and relations;
for example,
$ C [A, b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3]$
with relations

- $b_2*A-b_1*b_0=0$,
- $b_3*A-b_1*b_2=0$,
- $b_2^2-b_0*b_3=0$.

---

Using Macaulay2 package "Depth" I'm able to check if ring is Cohen-Macaulay, but I also need to compute for example $Ext^3_R(C, R)$. Only package I found for counting Ext's (namely Ext ) does it only for complete intersections (which are already Gorenstein). Is there a way to check if a commutative ring is Gorenstein?

Comment: Dear Qlzqlzuup, I really like your handle for its sheer euphony. If only you could get rid of the two pesky vowels it contains...

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5427v1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Macaulay2, version 1.3.1
i1 : S = QQ[A,b0,b1,b2,b3]

o1 = S

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : I=ideal(b2*A-b1*b0, b3*A-b1*b2, b2^2-b0*b3)

                                              2
o2 = ideal (- b0*b1 + A*b2, - b1*b2 + A*b3, b2  - b0*b3)

o2 : Ideal of S

i3 : R = S/I

o3 = R

o3 : QuotientRing

i4 : k = coker vars R

o4 = cokernel | A b0 b1 b2 b3 |

                            1
o4 : R-module, quotient of R

i5 : Ext^3(k,R^1)

o5 = cokernel {-2} | b3 b2 b1 b0 A 0  0  0  0  0 |
              {-2} | 0  0  0  0  0 b3 b2 b1 b0 A |

                            2
o5 : R-module, quotient of R
```

Socle dimension 2. Not Gorenstein.

Alternative method: find a regular sequence of length 3 and kill it. Here's one found by trial and error:

```
i27 : J=ideal (b1 - b2, A, b0 - b3)

o27 = ideal (b1 - b2, A, b0 - b3)

o27 : Ideal of R

i28 : res J

       1      3      3      1
o28 = R  <-- R  <-- R  <-- R  <-- 0

      0      1      2      3      4

o28 : ChainComplex

i29 : T = R/J

o29 = T

o29 : QuotientRing

i31 : Hom(coker vars T,T^1)

o31 = image | b3 b2 |

                              1
o31 : T-module, submodule of T

i32 : prune oo

o32 = cokernel {1} | b3 b2 0  0  |
               {1} | 0  0  b3 b2 |
```

Comment: Hi. Another sleek way could be using resolution of $I$. Since $I$ is homogeneous, I believe Macaulay2 computes minimal graded free resolution for $I$. 

i20 : res I

       1      3      2
o20 = S  <-- S  <-- S  <-- 0                            
      0      1      2      3

1) This shows that $I$ is Cohen-Macaulay (by Hilbert-Burch), but not Gorenstein by the same argument on Socle. 

2) Since ideal $I$ is of codimension $2$, it is locally Gorenstein if and only if it is complete intersection. However the first Betti number shows that it is minimally three generated.


Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Dear Graham, I did not mean the first line of my answer be a criticism of your answer. In fact, I am sure that for the OP this is much closer to what they wanted. My point was that while I have high appreciation for the usefulness of *Macaulay 2* or computational tools in general, it is sometimes useful to recognize the situation at hand. For me, it would have been difficult to figure out what you did, but  when I looked at the equations I thought of rank $1$ matrices and once I saw the geometry I knew what was happening. I thought it was worth sharing.

Comment: ps: I am also glad your solution is here, because the two sides together give a much more complete picture than either one would in themselves.

Comment: Dear Sándor, of course I was not offended.  You're right -- our answers complement each other. In fact, a full list of all the ways to answer this question might involve a pretty broad cross-section of commutative algebra and algebraic geometry. 

Answer (score 10):

Here is an alternative way to think about this without Macaulay.

Clearly, your equations look like $2\times 2$ determinants. In fact, sure enough, these are all the $2\times 2$ minors of the matrix:
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
A & b_0 & b_2 \\\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 
\end{matrix}
\right].
$$

So $\mathrm{Spec}\, R$ is a hypersurface in the cone $C\subset \mathbb A^6$ over the Segre embedding of $P=\mathbb P^2\times\mathbb P^1\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^5$. Therefore, $R$ is Gorenstein if and only if $C$ is, but $C$ isn't.

To see the latter note that being Gorenstein is equivalent to being Cohen-Macaulay and the dualizing sheaf being a line bundle (or perhaps you would prefer to say that the dualizing module is locally principal).

It is relatively easy to see that the dualizing sheaf of $C$ is not a line bundle. Since its an affine cone over a normal (actually smooth) projective variety, $\mathrm{Pic}\, C$ is trivial. Hence if 
the dualizing sheaf of $C$ were a line bundle it would be trivial. Then the dualizing sheaf of its projective closure in $\mathbb P^6$ would be also a line bundle, which as a divisor is supported at the hyperplane at infinity. That would imply that the dualizing sheaf of the original variety $P=\mathbb P^2\times\mathbb P^1$ is a multiple of the restriction of the hyperplane class of $\mathbb P^5$, but it is not, because it is the class $(-3,-2)$, whereas the hyperplane class is $(1,1)$.

Notice that this approach actually proves that this is not even $\mathbb Q$-Gorenstein, that is, that no (reflexive) power of the dualizing sheaf of $C$ is a line bundle. It is also clear, although this is probably easy to see from the ring already that the only localization that is not Gorenstein is at the vertex of the cone and all localizations at primes that are not contained in that maximal ideal are regular. Finally, it is also easy to see this way that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay. It follows by figuring out the cohomology of powers of the hyperplane class of the embedding on $P$.

Comment: Given that these computations seem to be relatively easy to do on a computer these days (see Graham Leuschke's answer) I think my main fear is that people like Sandor Kovacs might one day die out :-/ Then where would we be? 

Comment:   Dear @wccanard, you write "Then where would we be [When Sándor dies]?" Answer: in a much worse world. I study mathematics in order to understand what is going on. Pushing buttons and having an answer spit at me teaches me nothing. Long life to Sándor! 

Comment: I also wish Sándor [and all people 'like' and 'unlike' him] nothing but long life and happiness, but I do want to say that while my first answer is admittedly pretty black-boxy, the second one and Youngsu's comment following are both easy and instructive to do by hand, and that it's only by doing many such examples that we can get the kind of algebraic intuition that serves us [i.e. me] when we [i.e. I] meet examples that are not so susceptible to geometry.

Comment: I totally agree [with Graham]. It was lucky that I could recognize the geometry behind this particular example, but *Macaualy 2* is useful when that's hard to do.  

Comment: @Georges: Thanks for the support and the well wishing. The same to you!